# Serializing object as JSON without adding anything to prototype

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

Is there any JSON parser/stringifier for Javascript that **does not add anything to the prototype** (like Date.prototype)?

Because my script is going to be used as a third party script, I want to eliminate the conflicts it may cause.

I am not keen on writing my own serializer/desrializer beacuse probably this was done somewhere else, and better.

Comment: Just curious: what kind of conflicts are you thinking of?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is, if they are using a framework like Prototype that also adds Date.prototype.toJSON(), I will end up overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcel suggested Crockford's json2.js is nice option. Many modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox) have in-built JSON parser. If you use crockford's json2.js, it will automatically use native implementation if it is present, falling back to javascript implementation otherwise.

Comment: As Nimcap said in a comment to my now deleted answer, json2.js adds `Date.prototype.toJSON` and the like (see l. 175 ff.), so this isn't an option; at least not out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the source code of [json-sans-eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/) and it doesn't extend any object. It's only a JSON parser and not a generator, but it's at least something.

Source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/source/browse/trunk/src/json_sans_eval.js).